# Android app with Google Maps Android API 2.0, map doesn't move

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I made a small test app in order to test the Maps API 2. The map shows up, but doesn't seem to respond, neither to gestures nor code.

This is the code I have in the onCreate() method of the main Activity:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) 
            getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

    double lat;
    double lon;

    try 
    {
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lon = location.getLongitude();
    } 

    catch (NullPointerException e) 

    {
        lat = -1.0;
        lon = -1.0;
    }

    a.setText(String.valueOf(lat) + "," + String.valueOf(lon));

    GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1)).getMap();

    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    LatLng myLoc = new LatLng(lat, lon);

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Your current location").position(myLoc));

    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myLoc, 5));
```

The `lat` and `lon` variables get their correct values.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you run it on AVD? I had some similar issues when running on AVD. Switching to a physical device fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks but I tested it on a physical device, @shyam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. Seems like I was using the wrong SHA1 and key.